# Raphael JS nested canvases?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm using Raphael JS to draw vector graphics on a webpage, and I have a rectangle (Raphael.rect) that I'd like to use as a seperate canvas from its parent.
Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT:** I'd just draw in the rectangle like normal, but it wouldn't cut off the contents at its border.

Answer (score 0):

You currently can not use a Raphael `rect` as the equivalent of a regular Raphael object: nesting is unfortunately not supported. What you will probably have to do is use the position of the `rect` as an offset for all your drawing operations that should appear inside the `rect`.

Comment: That would work except for the fact that I want the parent rect to have it cut off the elements inside it at the borders, just as a Raphael object would. Any workarounds for this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently clip-rect works for this.
Oh the power of searching after all hope is lost.